# can't parse JSON data from php when using parse() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have trouble converting json data from PHP into javascript JSON format. When I use the responseText() function, I can see the that data was parsed successfully from PHP. But when I convert the ajax response to JSON, for example, `var json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)`, I don't see any information outputted to the screen. I don't mind jquery answers, but I would like to see at least an example in pure javascript.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_POST["height"])) {

    $height = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '.', $_POST['height']);
    $width = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '.', $_POST['width']);

    $areaInches = $height * $width;
    $areaCM = $areaInches * 0.00064516;

     $result = array(       
      'area_inches' =>  $areaInches,
      'area_cm' => $areaCM            
    );

    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

```js
function sendData() {
  var height, width;

  height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input_height').value);
  width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input_width').value);

  console.log(height);

  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

      var json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
      document.getElementById('jsondata1').innerHTML = json.area_inches + "ft^2";
      document.getElementById('jsondata2').innerHTML = json.area_cm + "cm^2";

      console.log(ajax.responseText);

    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }

  };

  ajax.open("POST", "calculate_area.php", true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajax.send('height=' + height +
    '&width=' + width
  );


}
```

```html
<h1>Calculate Area of Rectangle</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Height</label>
  <input id="input_height" class="clear" type="text">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Width</label>
  <input id="input_width" class="clear" type="text">
</div>
<br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <button onclick="sendData();">Calc. Area</button>
  <input id="jsondata1" class="mt" type="text" readonly>
  <input id="jsondata2" class="mt" type="text" readonly>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of a JSON result from the php script?

Comment: one suggestion is to set the response to be JSON from start `ajax.responseType = "json"` then you don't have to do `JSON.stringify(...)`

Comment: Also, since you are dealing with readonly inputs - you should do: `...ById('jsondata2').value =` and not `innerHTML`

Comment: @Endless, the JSON result from the php script outputs the following: {"area_inches":30000,"area_cm":19.3548}

Comment: Thanks, it's working when I use  innerHTML with a div element or value with an input element.

Comment: A small side note: you're providing square inches and labelling them as square feet. (`= json.area_inches + "ft^2";`)